# Failing basic AWS Glacier mocking using moto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, moto

I am trying to mock simple Glacier calls (creation and deletion of a Glacier vault) and can't find my way around this (despite being able to achieve such simple mocking with S3, creating a Bucket).

It seems that the mocking of Glacier simply isn't taken into account.

Code is as follows:

```py
import boto3
from moto import mock_glacier

with mock_glacier():
    glacier_resource = boto3.resource('glacier', region_name="fake-glacier-region")
    vault = glacier_resource.create_vault(accountId='-', vaultName="fake.glacier.name")
```

And I get the following exception at vault creation:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/<...>/test_mock_glacier.py", line 9, in test_simplest
    vault = glacier_resource.create_vault(accountId='-', vaultName="fake.glacier.name")
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 663, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 137, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 256, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/<...>/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 343, in send
    raise EndpointConnectionError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e)
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://glacier.fake-glacier-region.amazonaws.com/-/vaults/fake.glacier.name"
```

I am using boto3 v1.17.49 and moto v2.0.8 that I installed using `python3.7 -m pip install 'moto[all]'`

---

Providing a valid AWS region name leads to following exception:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the CreateVault operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

(while having set mock `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN`, `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` environment variables (with `'testing'` as value) as stated in moto's README)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I turned out to be a bug](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/3961) where a Glacier vault can not contain a `.` in its name.

[A fix](https://github.com/spulec/moto/pull/3964) is on its way (merged into master, to be released with version 2.0.9)

Quickfix was thus to change `vaultName="fake.glacier.name"` to `vaultName="fakeGlacierName"`.